# Lenovo ThinkPad P15 won't boot after disabling battery

Tags: bios, battery, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, charging

The battery on my P15 was no longer charging (the battery + charging symbol never appeared in the task tray).  I disabled the battery in the BIOS in an attempt to "reset" things.  The PC shutdown, and now it won't reboot, even with the power cable plugged in, presumably because it's not getting power from the adapter (the adapter itself works).

I've disconnected the main battery and the CMOS battery, held the power button, etc, but nothing will reset the BIOS.  I've bricked my laptop.  Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: Shut down for sure.   Wait for an hour or two.  Plug in and attempt to start and see if BIOS recovers.  If not, you will need to get the machine serviced.

Comment: Re-connect the battery. The charger's job is not to run the computer, it's to charge the battery. The battery is [when working] capable of supplying the extra power needed to kick the machine into boot. Without it, the charger may just not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem and here is what ended up working.

You likely have a power supply for your P15 vs. just USB-C/Thunderbolt right?

For me on an X1 Extreme Gen5, I had the exact same issue that the laptop wouldn't turn on after disabling the battery and plugging in the power adapter when I was ready to enable the battery again.  In my case the charge light for the adapter did not come on ever.

I tried disconnecting the laptop battery, removing the CMOS battery, using the reset button hole at the bottom, waiting an hour, holding down the power button for a long time, etc.  None of that worked.

What did end up working was connecting a Thunderbolt eGPU which delivers power and then the power adapter.  Then I finally got the charge light to come on and I was able to start the laptop.

You may be able to do the same thing just with USB-C power vs. an eGPU with power.  It seems to me there's some issue with the Lenovo laptops that utilize the non usb-c power adapters. I bet the UEFI expects TB/USB-C power for the reset and not the dedicated adapter.  The reason I say that is because the power adapter light never came on except with the USB-C power.

I honestly feel like I had to jumpstart my laptop.  I don't like these software/hardware linked functions.  Next time, I will either not bother disabling the battery or if I'm concerned disconnect the battery first thing after opening the case instead.

Good luck!